# Como agregar parametros a un boton desde 'Codigo Java' en Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Esto es algo me no logro conseguir por más que intento, lo que quiero es esto:

[image: ...]

Estas propiedades agregarselas pero en el codigo de Java...

[image: ...]

Me pueden explicar como haria esto?, quiero agregar la propiedad android:layout_weight a un Button que esta dentro de un TableRow de un TableLayout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes definir un [**LayoutParams**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) a tu botón, en donde puedes definir programaticamente ancho y alto, por medio de las propiedades `MATCH_PARENT` o `WRAP_CONTENT`, **ademas del peso**  (último parámetro):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
```

incluso puedes definir ancho y alto en pixeles, como ejemplo 500 px de ancho y 500 px de alto, además del peso (último parámetro):

```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500, 1.0f);
```

---

De esta forma puedes progamaticamente definir propiedades de peso, además de ancho y algo a tus vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo debes hacer con la propiedad LayoutParams.

Así :

```
button.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(x,y,z));
```

Según la Documentación de Android la firma del constructor es la siguiente.

```
LayoutParams(int width, int height, float weight)
```

Fuentes: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224193/set-the-layout-weight-of-a-textview-programmatically) [Android Doc's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)